# Is there a way to control the animation on a UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I would like to modify the animation duration and attach a callback to be called when the animation finishes when calling scrollToRowAtIndexPath with animated:YES but I can't find a handle to its animation proxy or any other way to do it.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `TableView delegate`, implement

`-scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:`

This will get called once the scroll animation has completed.

Comment: Fantastic, any idea how to change the duration?

Comment: That I don't think you can do. You could set up your own animation, I'm not sure but I believe that the contentOffset property is animatable.

Comment: Is there a way to detect if the animation did not happen? There is an edge case where the table view does not need to scroll, than scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation does not trigger